# How to make span element opaque, but keep opacity?

Tags: html, css

I have a span element that serves as a resizing bar. It's current CSS is:

```
.Resizer {
  background: whitesmoke;
  opacity: .2;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*-moz-background-clip: padding;*/
  /*-webkit-background-clip: padding;*/
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

However, I'm able the content behind the resizer bar. If I drag the resizer bar over a div that has non-flex content, the resizer bar overlaps the div and I'm able to see through the resizer bar. How can I keep the opacity, but have bar be opaque?

Comment: *How can I keep the opacity, but have bar be opaque?* - Sorry, what?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Wut.

Comment: I think he means, "how do I keep the element at 0.2 opacity, but have the sub-element be at 1 opacity"

Comment: @Tasgali Yes, that is exactly what I mean. I want to keep the resizer bar styling, which has an opacity of 0.2, but I don't want the element to be transparent.

Comment: Parent opacity always changes child opacity. use colors.

Comment: That question could definitely have been worded better ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `opacity` field, give the element a background color using `rgba`. ex:

```
.Resizer {
  background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.2);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  ...
```

The opacity field has a cumulative effect on all sub-elements, making anything it contains at least as translucent. Using the background doesn't.